# Responsive background image overlays content

Tags: html, css

I have the following piece of code:
http://jsfiddle.net/xyoes1wy/

I have an issue where the image in the `footer` overlays my main body content. What is causing this? How can I fix this?

***CSS:***

```
.container {
    background-image:url('http://www.imagesman.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Landscape-wallpapers-1.jpeg');
  background-size:100%;
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-position:bottom center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#content {
    z-index:2;
    height:700px
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add position:relative to the #content element for the z-index to work.

```
#content {
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    height:700
}
```

Comment: I have just made that update here: http://jsfiddle.net/xyoes1wy/1/ but the image is now behind the text. I need it to be below the text completely.

Comment: That's because the content has is wrapped inside a div with the class container (which has the background). I moved it around a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/8awm96an/

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tirpox/xyoes1wy/3/)
I have removed two .container from the header and content wrapper, because you don't want to display content in absolute elements, usually. If you want to position it, you could still put in a relative block and set top/left attributes for it.

```
.container {
    background-image:url('http://www.imagesman.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Landscape-wallpapers-1.jpeg');
    background-size:100%;
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-position:bottom center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#content {
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    height:100%
}

footer {
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
}
```